# Option to change database compatibility level disabled in SSMS2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, ssms-2012

I'm trying to use SQL Server Management Studio 2012 to alter the **Compatibility level** of a database, but the drop-down is disabled:

[image]

Why is the option disabled? How do i enable it?

I try manually changing it using T-SQL:

```
ALTER DATABASE AsiQuanClient
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL =  110; --90 | 100 | 110
```

and it is still disabled:

[image]

Why is it disabled, and how do i enabled it?

## Bonus Chatter

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  11.0.3128.0

```
SELECT @@version

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) 
    Dec 28 2012 20:23:12 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Any idea of someone who is connecting with SSMS2012 from Windows-7 has same issues? Additionally according to [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933794.aspx) the only permission required is "ALTER DATABASE" p.s. can't replicate it with Windows-7 in my environment.

Comment: @SaUce You indirectly solved it. While a user does not need to be a server admin to change a database compatibility level, they do need to be a server admin in order for the drop-down to be enabled. Copy that into an answer and you'll get an accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933794.aspx) the only permission required is "ALTER DATABASE"

OP writes:
"While a user does not need to be a server admin to change a database compatibility level, they do need to be a server admin in order for the drop-down to be enabled."

Answer (score 0):

The account you are using is a member of serveradmin ( allowing you to access the database properties menu ) but is not in db_owner or another sufficiently privileged role to perform the compatibility change on the catalog.

Edit; beaten by OP

Comment: The same user is allowed to run the `ALTER DATABASE` command; just not use the UI to do it.